# Is there a way to iterate through all features of a layer and change the styling of specific features?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a dataset of ~1,000 points I am displaying on a website. I want to create a function that specifically changes the color of points meeting a specific criteria (e.g., all points that have "x" attribute turn to red.

Is there a way to iterate through the layer and manually change the style of each point?

This is my current code

```
map.on('load', function () {
    map.addSource('base_points', {
        type: 'geojson',
        data: 'https://api.mapbox.com/datasets/v1/shgis-kennethdean/ckj4dso370j2s22pkgjjgy0x1/features?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic2hnaXMta2VubmV0aGRlYW4iLCJhIjoiY2tqMTBpOHl0MDI0YzJ5c2IzOHMyM2V4eCJ9.DFNMWEGdVJkBh9mS2OkrbA'
    });

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "base_points",
        "type": "circle",
        "source": "base_points",
        "paint": {
            "circle-stroke-width": 1,
            "circle-stroke-color": "#000000",
            "circle-radius": 5,
            "circle-color": '#a6cee3',
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Just check [this](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/data-driven-circle-colors/) out on how to create a circle layer data-driven color change